# ACF wp_query, get the final field of the chain, which is located in => repeater-> field-> repeater-> FIELD

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The final field is PASSWORD, as I mark in the image 
This is the code of how I tried to get the field..

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'yanco_posts_where');
function yanco_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace( "meta_key = 'repeater_machines_password_repeater_$", "meta_key LIKE 'repeater_machines_%_password_repeater_%", $where );
    return $where;
}

    if(isset($_GET['password'])) {
        $password = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['password'] );
        $meta_query[] = array(
            // 'key' => 'repeater_machines_$_password', // Format: repeater_field + _ + $ + _ + repeater_sub_field password_repeater
            'key' => 'repeater_machines_$_country_password_repeater_$_password',
            'value' => $password,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What you try to do exactly?
Did you try to get field according to ACF Codex, something like this https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/repeater-while-detect-last/

Comment: I just want to make my search field work. For it, I need to catch the last field in repeater and put it into the KEY.

Comment: The problem is that, that I have repeater > field + repeater > and in this repeater I have a text field, that I need to catch and put to into the KEY in meta_query. I really appreciate your reply! Thanks a lot, hope you can help me

Comment: As you can see on that link, you can use count() to get number of repeaters, and with that value you can create if state to get text field value in last repeater.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count()` to get number of repeaters, and with that value you can create `if` state, to get text field value in last repeater.
Also, like in example that i send you in comment, you can create counter `$i`, that you will use like compare in `if` condition.
You can pass second argument like Post ID, if you don't use query.

```
<?php
$count_repeater = count( get_field('nameOfRepeater', $post->ID) );
    if($i == $count_repeater) {
     // Get value from text field in last repeater
     $text_value = get_field('nameOfTextField', $post->ID);
    }
```

Comment: Okay. I understand.But in any case, I need to use query to make my search work. Any ideas how to put it in ‘KEY’ => ... ?

Comment: So you want to pass in KEY last repeater that you create, and by that key value you want to do search?

Comment: yes, exactly. But the last repeater field, is located in that chain that I mentioned in this post.. I don’t understand how to do it..(

Comment: Did you try to do some another logic for that?

Comment: I think you miss number in the end of KEY that will represent last repeater and to pass slug from field, check this answer loop https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/nested-repeaters-using-get-post-meta/

Comment: Also, did you try get_field_object() ? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/

Comment: if I do as you told, then iI need to put $value into my ‘KEY’ => $value ? to make my search field works ?

Comment: Something like this  $repeater.'_'.$i.'_'.$nested_repeater.'_'.$j.'_sub_field_name'. $i and $j represent number of repeaters

Comment: You have similar value in key, as you show in example. I thing it’s possible that $ dont represent number correctly. Did you try to hardcode number of repeaters?

Comment: For now in Database I have such chain `repeater_machines_0_password_repeater_0_password` But I need to connect the last field (password) to each country So, in Database I should have such chain: `repeater_machines_country_password_repeater_0_password`
Instead of number - put a COUNTRY value (for example ITALY) to database (Is it possible ?)